Brezis's Exercise 1.10
Exercise 1.10 says: 
The solutions given by the book is: 
Here is when I have doubts. How we know that $g$ is well define. I think that there could exists an element $x\in G$ that can be represented as $x=\sum_{i\in J_{1}}\beta_{i}x_{i}=\sum_{i\in J_{2}}\gamma_{i}x_{i}$. How do we know that $\sum_{i\in J_{1}}\beta_{i}\alpha_{i}=\sum_{i\in J_{2}}\gamma_{i}\alpha_{i}$?
I have tried to prove this using part (B) but I couldn't. I think I am missing something for proving this uniquenness. Any hint for proving this uniqueness will be appreciated.

$\sum_{i\in J_{1}}\beta_{i}x_{i}=\sum_{i\in J_{2}}\gamma_{i}x_{i}$ can be wriiten in the form $\sum_{i\in J}\gamma_{i}x_{i}=0$ where $J=J_{1}\cup J_2$.

One way to see this is to consider first the vector space $\mathbb R[I]$ with basis $I$ (the subspace of the space of $\mathbb R$-valued functions on $I$ spanned by the indicator functions of the elements of $I$). Clearly there is a unique linear functional $\tilde{g}\colon \mathbb R[I] \to \mathbb R$ which satisfies $g(i)= \alpha_i$ for all $i \in I$. Now if $\phi \colon \mathbb R[I] \to E$ is the linear map given by $\phi(i)= x_i$, condition $(B)$ can be rephrased as saying that
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
|\tilde{g}(v)|\leq M.\|\phi(v)\|, \quad \forall v \in \mathbb R[I]
$$
In particular, if $v \in \ker(\phi)$ then $|\tilde{g}(v)|\leq M.\|\phi(v)\|=0$, so that $\tilde{g}(v)=0$. Thus $\ker(\phi)\subseteq \ker(\tilde{g})$. But then clearly if $G = \text{im}(\phi)\leq E$, and $v \in G$, we have $v = \phi(u)$ for some $u \in \mathbb R[I]$ and setting $g(v) = \tilde{g}(u)$  we obtain a well-defined linear functional $g\colon G \to \mathbb R$. Moreover, it follows from $(\dagger)$ that $|g(v)|\leq M.\|v\|$, so that $g$ is continuous. But then $g$ extends to a continuous linear functional on $E$ by the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Thank you so much!

You're welcome!
